# Add ip of host to hosts.allow

Tags: bash, cron

I use a machine with dynamic ip and dyndns to manage other remote machines. What i'd like to be able to do is for the remote machines to check the ip of the dyndns hostname ie

```
dig +short unix.stackexchange.com
```

and the resulting ip to be added to the end of a line in hosts.allow using a bash script so I can run it every 24 hours.

Comment: Don't. `hosts.allow` accepts DNS names.

Comment: doesn't work with dyndns

Comment: Oh you are right, a reverse DNS entry is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge here is to make sure you delete the previous one too, so I would add some sort of flag along with your IP in the hosts.allow. Something like "My DynDNS Server". So in your script you would first delete the flagged row (make sure there are not other rows with this!!):

```
grep -v "My DynDNS Server" /etc/hosts.allow > /tmp/hosts.allow
mv /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.allow.old
mv /tmp/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.allow
```

And then add the new one:

```
echo $service : `dig +short unix.stackexchange.com` : allow "# My DynDNS Server" >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good thinking but cat /etc/hosts.allow | grep -v "My DynDNS Server" > /etc/hosts.allow just creats a blank hosts.allow?

Comment: `cat` is useless, `grep` can open files on its own. Redirections from/to the same file are dangerous, you risk losing the entire file. Use a temporary file.

Comment: It shouldn't make it blank cause I'm greping one line off it, but I have edited to provide a most secure solution.

Comment: we're getting close but it adds the ip onto a new line it needs to go on the end of line 14 which starts sshd: IP, IP, IP, IP, IP,

Comment: it's ok sussed it put a \ at the end of the line. Thanks for your hrlp everyone